# Use ExtJS6.0 with Yii2

Tags: extjs, yii2

I want to configure ExtJS 6.0 ([desktop template](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/classic/desktop/index.html)) with Yii2 basic application template (not through [ext4yii](http://www.ext4yii.com)) but I don't know how to proceed. Can somebody help me by providing tips ?

**Edit**

I'm using the basic template.

Comment: As alway, it depends. Yii can do both backend and frontend; but since you want to use ExtJS in the frontend, I guess that you use Yii for the backend only? Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander. I'm using the basic template.